# real time update from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that's doing calls for firebase database and return those data. I'm trying to implement a listener to this function so when the database updates, the content in my web site also updates without refresh.

My function is as follows

```
export const loadBookings = async () => {
    const providersSnapshot = await firebase.database().ref('products').once('value');
    const providers = providersSnapshot && providersSnapshot.val();

    if (!providers) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return providers;
};
```

After going through some documentation i have tried changing itto something like this

```
const providersSnapshot = await firebase.database().ref('products').once('value');
    let providers = "";
    providersSnapshot.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        providers = snapshot.val();
    });
```

But the code doesn't work like that. How can i listen in real time for my firebase call?

Answer (score 0):

Use [on('value')](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) instead of `once('value')`.  `once()` just queries a single time (as its name suggests).  `on()` adds a listener that will get invoked repeatedly with changes as they occur.

I suggest reading over the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) to find an example of using `on()`.  It shows:

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: Where i'm confused is i don't have a method similar to 'updateStarCount' to use. I just want to assign the data to a variable

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the snapshot in the callback.

Comment: providersSnapshot.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        providers = snapshot.val();
    });

Something like this?

Comment: Sure, whatever you want.